# Angular - more than 1 routes how to organize

Tags: angular

I am trying to organize my app component for a new project and I have some issue with routing in Angular 8:

In general I have a landing page which is my first page. When I want to login in landing page I want to redirect user to /login without using main router outlet :
As you can see below:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent },
      { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
     ]
```

And this is my AppComponent:

`<app-top-nav-bar></app-top-nav-bar>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 <app-footer></app-footer>`

Now I want to know, how can I add second router inside MainComponent. When I open the app, I want to see mainComponent with it's own module and router. I have second module and router. I want to modularize my app : see this https://dzone.com/articles/howto-modularize-an-angular-application-by-example

Comment: Put your wildcard route at the end. The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.

Comment: It's <router-outlet></router-outlet> not <outlet></outlet>

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I edited my questions. I know how the routing works in general , I want to know how can I redirect my app to 2 different module , like auth and mainmodule? How I should organize my mdoule to have its own routing and components.  see https://dzone.com/articles/howto-modularize-an-angular-application-by-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `children`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, 
    children: [ 
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'mypath', pathMatch: 'full' }
      { path: 'mypath', component: MyComponent }
    ] 
  },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
]
```

Then just add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag inside your `MainComponent` `html` in the place where you wish to show the child component.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it is working now with children , also lazy loading and angular child also works.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Try changing your component to

```
<topnavbar></topnavbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it is router-outlet,  I edited my question. How can I redirect to another module with its own router and components. Imagine I want to redirect my app to auth or main module. see https://dzone.com/articles/howto-modularize-an-angular-application-by-example

Comment: Have you looked into lazy loading with angular modules?
https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules